# Script of "sys.all_objects" view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for source code or script of "sys.all_objects" view for drilling down how Microsoft is writing code as well as knowing the detail of default system tables.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run:

```
sp_helptext 'sys.all_objects'
```

Comment: Thank you. It is helpful..
But I was drilling down the view by the way 
sp_helptext 'sys.all_objects';

sp_helptext 'sys.objects';

sp_helptext 'sys.system_objects'

and found “sys.syspalnames”. I do not know if it is a table or View?

Comment: @RashedulIslam https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/object-catalog-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @IvanStarostin, Thank you for your replay. But I was looking for some System table in which SQL server storing data system data for managing SQL server objects. So far, I am accessing Views in all stored procedure like 'Sp_Help'. Actually, I am looking for Tables.